# How to display and image in imageview from spinner selection

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I would like to be able to select an item from the `Spinner` and for that item to be displayed in an `ImageView`. I have tried doing this and my sample code is below.  Is there another way of doing this?

Activity Class

```
    public class Campsites  extends Activity{ 
            @Override 
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
                setContentView(R.layout.campsites); 


                Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1); 
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Camp_Site_Facilities, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); 
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
                spinner.setAdapter(adapter); 
            }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
            int pos, long id) {

            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageResource(0);
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageResource(R.drawable.bergendal1);


    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Another interface callback
    }
}
```

Layout XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:src="@drawable/elephant" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

i have created this in strings

```
 <string-array name="Camp_Site_Facilities">
    <item>Berg en Dal</item>
    <item>Crocodile Bridge</item>
    <item>Letaba</item>
    <item>Lower Sabie</item>
    <item>Mopani</item>
    <item>Olifants</item>
    <item>Orpen</item>
    <item>Pretoriuskop</item>
    <item>Punda Maria</item>
    <item>Satara</item>
    <item>Shingwedzi</item>
    <item>Skukuza</item>
</string-array>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: are you facing any trouble with this code or just waiting for a better one?

Comment: Well it just doesn't seem to work. this spinner works fine but nothing happens when i select a item.  So i am not quite sure what code i need to display the image after i have selected the item from the spinner.  a Better code for this would be extremely helpfull. :-)

Comment: i think you need to set the listener for spinner... I am not able to find the code where you set the listener for spinner. try the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if this works

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    // your code for setting the image based on the item clicked....here
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
    // your code here
}

});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but it just brings up the image but can't switch between the images.  do i need to place another string in for the images or would you be kind to show me the code for switching images. all my images are in the res/drawable folder.  Its my first time working with the spinner.

Comment: try maintaining a hashmap with a string and an integer where string are the names in Camp_Site_Facilities array and integers are the R.drawable.bergendal1 ones.
I am not sure but give a try

Comment: Okay thanks, will give that a try. thanks for your help.  If that doesn't work i'll let you know. I think then i will just go back to sliding drawer and do it that way.